# How to populate GUI with ethernet data? (Java)

Tags: java, user-interface, ethernet

Currently developing a GUI in Java that communicates through Ethernet. It is designed to send data through one port and receive data through the other. The data received is used to populate a dynamic section of the GUI that changes with the data received that unfortunately must also be scaled to fit on the screen. My question is how using Java would I go about populating part of the GUI with a scaled version of the Ethernet data received?

Using swing for the display and awt for the listener. Data is received from java socket. Still unclear on exact way received data is packaged but trying to get a base idea on how to populate the virtual screen. separate thread to populate the screen most likely but also how to actually populate the screen with scaled version.

The GUI is designed to emulate a physical display unit with physical buttons and graphical display (colored words as well as arrows and other graphics, original idea was to just map it pixel for pixel but scaling throws me off).

Here is a snippet of the code, the virtual screen is not populated at the moment, just white outline and the communication port is not opened yet (all McduPanel does is paint static image to the screen, and setKey just sets a String variable based on the button pressed and sends it through the open port):

```
private McduPanel mPanel;

public McduGui() {

  mPanel = new McduPanel();

  GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
  GraphicsDevice vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
  JFrame window = new JFrame();

  window.addMouseListener(new MouseClickHandler());
  window.add(mPanel);
  window.setUndecorated(true);
  window.setResizable(false);
  vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);
  window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  try {
    getPorts();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);                                                                                                                                                               
  }
}

public static class MouseClickHandler implements MouseListener {

  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    int screenX = me.getXOnScreen();
    int screenY = me.getYOnScreen();
    System.out.println("screen(X,Y) = " + screenX + "," + screenY);
    setKey(screenX,screenY);
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
  }

  @OverrideDo 
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
  }
}

public static void getPorts() throws IOException {

  String screen = "host"; //host name
  String charData = "host"; //host name

  int screenPort = 71;//Integer.parseInt(71);
  int charPort = 72;//port number

  Socket echoSocket = new Socket(screen, 71);

  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
  BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
}
```

To further clarify:

A static image is painted to the screen with Strings mapped to positions on the screen that will send the String associated to that position every time it sees a mouse press. There is a virtual screen within the GUI that will change based on data received from port. It is up in the air what that data will be right now, but by design it is supposed to be the exact same as what physical screen looks like.

Best example I can give is think of a gameboy, the gameboy image is static on the panel, but virtual screen keeps updating based on the data received from the port. That box needs to be refreshed and more than likely scaled from the original size.

Comment: This is exactly what I do in android. How does Your metadata about the gui elements look like?

Comment: I'm sure you'd use `TCP/IP` or `UDP` and not read data directly from ethernet. Are you working with `JSON`?
Can you tell us what you are trying to do?

Comment: Show your code. Tell use how you receive data. Tell us your GUI framework - Swing? SWT? Tell use your concrete problem. There are a million ways.

Comment: The GUI is to emulate a physical console. Whatever is on the console screen needs to be on the GUI's virtual screen. The data as designed right now will be packaged and sent via Ethernet by another machine. We are not using JSON. And could you clarify on what metadata you are asking about?

Comment: A console? So your GUI is a text field? Really? Whatever, show your code.

Comment: Thank for your edit. I feel we are on a good way, dude. Now we know that you use Java + Swing and we can guess that you use some GUI components. So, you populate a JTextField by calling `field.setText("some text");`. And now post your code :) Or at least an example which shows your problem. I think you have less then 10 minutes until you question gets closed.

Comment: Do you know how to read from the BufferedReader (e.g. to get a String)? Do you know how to create thread? Do you know how to "render" your data (e.g. could you render a String like "this is a test" to the screen? Are you using JButtons or do you paint those stuff by hand?

Comment: mapped based on pixel locations of screen, so no actual buttons actually there. I know how to read from BufferedReader, vaguely familiar with threads but don't need to much detail can tackle myself. Rendering not so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I really tried hard to understand your problem. I am still not sure if your problem is painting, threads or reading from a socket, but I made a runnable example. The code is super ugly, but you can execute it as it is. The code create a "test server" which writes to a port every some seconds and a "test client" which reads from this port every some seconds. After the client read some text, it will print it on the screen.

Note that this is just an example - super ugly as I said, but it runs right out of the box. Also not that I strongly recommend to not paint any stuff! Use JButtons to display buttons and JTextFields (or JTextAreas) to display text. Do not print it by painting on the screen!

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RemoteConsole extends JPanel {

    private String text = "Start";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // your class is called McduPanel
        RemoteConsole remoteConsole = new RemoteConsole();

        // JFrame which contains all components
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(remoteConsole);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4564);

        // this is a test server which just writes "test"
        // to a port every 1 seconds
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4564);
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println("send");
                        out.println("test");
                        sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }.start();

        // a test client which checks the port every 1.5 seconds
        // and paints the text to a JPanel
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    while (true) {
                        String message = in.readLine();
                        System.out.println("received: " + message);
                        remoteConsole.appendText(message);
                        remoteConsole.repaint();
                        sleep(1500);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString(text, 75, 100);
    }

    public void appendText(String text) {
        this.text += text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unable to run as is in NetBeans. Accessing within inner class causing issues. I do however see slightly where you going with this.

Comment: I did not have any problems with Java 8 in Eclipse.

Comment: updating to 8 and will check

Comment: Or post your error. Make `serverSocket` final, maybe.

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class remoteconsole.RemoteConsole
Java Result: 1

Comment: Mmm... Some issue with your project. Have you added your package declaration `package remoteconsole;` on top of the class?

Comment: That fixed it my error. Silly me forgot package :/ and it needed final. It answers chunk of my question. Edited my original question to try to further clarify. The data sent ideally will be image that can be repainted to the screen (up in the air still communicating that). Issue is may need to be scaled down to fit.

Comment: I appreciate all the effort you put into helping. It became obvious that my question was to vague. Still new to stack overflow :p. You definitely steered me toward fully tackling this problem. Thanks for all the help!